# Make request with HTTPS proxy in python

Tags: python, https, proxy

my VPN provider (NordVP) just closed all the HTTP ports on its proxy servers. I can confirm with `cURL` that the HTTPS ports are working correctly, for example the following works:

```
curl -x https://proxy_server:89 --proxy-user username:password -L url
```

while this has just stop working:

```
curl -x http://proxy_server:80 --proxy-user username:password -L url
```

it used to work two days ago. In python I'm trying to make HTTP request using the `request` module:

```py
import requests
proxies = {
  "https":"https://user:password@proxy_server:port"
}

response = requests.get("https://api64.ipify.org?format=json", proxies=proxies)
print(response.text)
```

but I get the following 3 errors:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api64.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api64.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

I saw there is a very old question about the subject but it doesn't seem relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a workaround:

```java
Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
    @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Proxy-Authorization", credential).build();
    }
};

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);
        .socketFactory(new DelegatingSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()))
        .build();
```

On Android add this to your gradle:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.0'
```

and this to your app `onCreate()`:

```java
Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6561